# How can i post information from a external generated php file on to wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, import, opencart, feed

Hy guys,
I'm not so familiar with php-wordpress so any help is welcome. I managed to extract information from a sql OpenCart platform but now I need to import that information into WordPress. If anyone has any idea I would appreciate.
The outpoted information looks like this:

**This is the cathegory, subcategory, Model, product id, product name:** Femei > Fuste||EPS094|51|Fusta din brocart|

**This is the description:**
 Fusta "baby-doll" din brocart, usor evazata, de culoare roz, din bumbac 100%. Are aplicata in partea de jos o dantela fina roz.

Lungime: 48 cm.

**this is the generated link, price, image link and availability:**
|http://allboutique.ro/fusta-din-brocart.html?utm_source=testal3&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=direct_link|http://allboutique.ro/image/data/Femei/Untitled-3.jpg|79.99|RON||In stock|

This is just for one product, and i need to make a someking of php that can import this products to a category wordpress.

Thank you very much for assisting me!
Cheers,
Alex

If need i can post a link to the external file so that u can see the generated info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an webservice of your php file and then you can ask the informations with jQuery and JavaScript on the client.

Some pseudo code:

Server:

```
<?php
    echo 'Your informations, JSON format would be awesome!';
?>
```

Client:

```
...
<p id="myobject">Loading...</p>
<script>
    $.ajax({
      url: "the url to your php file",
      context: document.body
    }).done(function(r) {
      $('#myobject').text(r);
    });
</script>
...
```

Result should be something like this:

```
<p id="myobject">Your informations, JSON format would be awesome!</p>
```

As next step you can implement [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) to transfer your data simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, i really apriciate it! I will give it a try then ill give u my feedback.

Comment: Here is the link where u can see the generated information http://allboutique.ro/datafeed_testal3_opencart.php

Comment: you should convert this to json, use 'json_encode' in php on your object (http://de.php.net/json_encode)